# How to get identical short and long chapter names in two documents?

Tags: cross-referencing, memoir, xr

**Background**

I use `memoir` to typeset a textbook and a solution manual. For those chapters in the textbook that have problems, I have a corresponding chapter in the solution manual. Needless to say, I want to have consistent chapter numbering and titles for the corresponding chapters, but I do not want to have to enter them twice.

**MWEs**

The following MWEs illustrate what I'm doing now--which does nearly all I want. The first (textbook) file, called `doc1.tex` is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A Chapter}
\chapter{Another Chapter}
\label{doc1:another_chapter}
\chapter{Yet Another Chapter}
\chapter[Final Chapter Short]{Final Chapter\\Long} % note short and long titles
\label{doc1:final_chapter}
\end{document}
```

The second (solution manual file) is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{refcount}
\newcounter{newcounter}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{doc1}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setcounterref{newcounter}{doc1:another_chapter}
\setcounter{chapter}{\thenewcounter}
\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}
\chapter{Another Chapter}
\setcounterref{newcounter}{doc1:final_chapter}
\setcounter{chapter}{\thenewcounter}
\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}
\chapter{\titleref{doc1:final_chapter}}
\end{document}
```

So in the solution manual I have two chapters; the first is "Chapter 2" and the second is "Chapter 4".

**Problem**

The problem is that the `titleref` command gives me the short (destined for toc) chapter title for the second chapter in the solution manual (Chapter 4) whereas I want the long title.

Based on what I read in the `memoir` v3.7b manual (specifically at the bottom of p. 297), this appears to be the expected behaviour and there appears to be no way to get the long name as the chapter name.

**Question**

How can I modify the MWEs above to get `memoir` to give me the long name in the document itself and the short name in the toc? (A crude fallback solution would be to put all `\chapter[short title]{long title}` into separate `.tex` files and then using `\input`ing them in both documents.)

Answer (score 2):

When the document is compiled, it creates a file named `chapterlist` which defines a series of macros.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% provides \expandonce

\newwrite\myfile
\AtBeginDocument{\openout\myfile=chapterlist}
\AtEndDocument{\closeout\myfile}% not really necessary

\newcommand{\mychapter}[2][\empty]% #1 = short title (optional), #2 = long title
{\bgroup
  \def\foo{#2}% local definition
  \ifx\empty#1\relax
    \chapter{#2}
    \immediate\write\myfile{\string\newcommand{\string\mychapter\Roman{chapter}}}
    \addtocounter{chapter}{-1}%
    \immediate\write\myfile{\string{\string\setcounter{chapter}{\thechapter}\string\chapter{\expandonce\foo}\string}}%
  \else
    \chapter[#1]{#2}
    \immediate\write\myfile{\string\newcommand{\string\mychapter\Roman{chapter}}}
    \addtocounter{chapter}{-1}%
    \immediate\write\myfile{\string{\string\setcounter{chapter}{\thechapter}\string\chapter[#1]{\expandonce\foo}\string}}%
  \fi
  \stepcounter{chapter}%
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\mychapter{A Chapter}
\mychapter{Another Chapter}
\label{doc1:another_chapter}
\mychapter{Yet Another Chapter}
\mychapter[Final Chapter Short]{Final Chapter\\Long}
\label{doc1:final_chapter}
\end{document}
```

This file is then input into the solution version to recreate the chapters.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\input{chapterlist}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\mychapterII
\mychapterIV
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With answers package one can get all in one solution. Here is an example

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{answers}
\Opensolutionfile{sm}[SolutionManual]%  %write to file SolutionManual.tex

\Writetofile{sm}{%                      %SolutionManual.tex preambl
\string\documentclass{memoir}^^J%
\string\begin{document}^^J%
\string\tableofcontents}

\AtEndDocument{%
\Writetofile{sm}{%                     %SolutionManual.tex bye
\string\end{document}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\smadd}[1]{%
\immediate\write\sm@file{%
\string\setcounter{chapter}{\thechapter}}
\immediate\write\sm@file{%
\unexpanded{#1}}%
#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\smadd{\chapter[Foo bar]{Very long foo}}
Bla bla of the chapter

\begin{Filesave}{sm}
Solution manual Contents
\end{Filesave}

\chapter{Bar}
\chapter{Baz}

\smadd{\chapter[Baz baz]{Very very long baz}}
Bla bla of the chapter

\begin{Filesave}{sm}
Solution manual Contents
\end{Filesave}

\end{document}
```

This will creat a ready to use `SolutionManual.tex`